# ssh forwarding from mac to ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, centos

I'm trying to use ssh forwarding feature on mac to display remote GUI application locally.

on Mac, I installed the official xserver XQaurtz, set it up as below.

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host *
    XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
```

Then I used "ssh -v -X user@remote_machine" to login a ubuntu machine, then used xclock to test.

```
$ ssh -v -X user@remote_machine
OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/bwu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
```

On remote machine, xclock failed to launch due to $DISPLAY is empty.

```
$ xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

I did two more tests.

> 1. From the same mac, ssh login to another centos 7 machine, it's working.  $ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config X11Forwarding yes
>      X11DisplayOffset 0
> 2. From a ubuntu host, ssh login to above ubuntu machine, it's working. $ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config X11Forwarding yes X11DisplayOffset 0

So we got below results.

> ```
> mac to centos, working
> ubuntu to ubuntu, working
> mac to ubuntu, not working
> ```

```
Test 1 indicates the issue might locate on remote ubuntu machine.
Test 2 indicates the issue might locate on local mac machine.
```

What's wrong with this? Did I miss anything?

Comment: Can you try the trusted X11 forwarding ? `ssh -v -Y user@remote_machine`

Comment: I thought I tried that before, neither working. Just tried it again, 'ssh -v -Y' showed more messages, then I tried 'ssh -v -X', this time it's working. It also showed more messages, especially "debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.". Previous attempts never saw this 'Requesting X11' message. 

Puzzled by this, don't know what happened.

Comment: It's not working again, crazy.

>$ ssh -v -Y user@remote_machine
>OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
>debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/bwu/.ssh/config
>debug1: /Users/bwu/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
>debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
>debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
>debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master

>$ xclock
>Error: Can't open display: localhost:0.0
>$ echo $DISPLAY
>localhost:0.0

Answer (score 0):

Further update on this issue. I noticed x11 forwarding did not work "randomly" on centos or ubuntu (from my macbook), but after a couple hours it may work again.

I checked the sshd configuration on both centos and ubuntu, nothing special and they are same in x11 forwarding part. I don't know why.

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 0
#X11UseLocalhost yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that might work. I had the same problem and this is how I solved it. Give the following solution a try.

> First find the DISPLAY variable.

> So in your mac if you type as a normal user

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

> Then what you would get is something like the following.

```
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.0aQYNoXMFK/org.xquartz:0
```

> Then try something like

```
xeyes
```

> to see whether forwarding works. There are other apps you could try, but I like this one.

And now you know that your display is working

Now if you want to try the same as root (Please don't jump on me guys, I know some of you all are strongly against root access)    `echo $DISPLAY`, but if does not work

> then in your root prompt do the following

```
export DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.0aQYNoXMFK/org.xquartz:0
```

The same you found in your normal user account. Then copy your
.Xauthority at /Users/normal user/.Xauthority to /var/root/.

> The .Xauthority file is already there, but this would over right it.

```
cp /Users/normal user/.Xauthority /var/root/
```

Of course the export might work, but there is no harm in doing the above.

> Now try the following.

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

> And you should see the following

```
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.0aQYNoXMFK/org.xquartz:0
```

If you `ssh` into Ubuntu from normal user prompt then you do not need to do the root part, but since, I use root to `ssh` into my Ubuntu systems I often have to do this.

> Then when you 'ssh into Ubuntu type

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

> And you would see something like the following

```
localhost:10.0
```

The above would work if you have done all those other bits like forwarding and etc.

Again, if you want to use root in your Ubuntu and if the `echo $DISPLAY` does not produce any response,

> then try the following (Assuming you are at root prompt).

```
cp /home/user name/.Xauthority /root/.Xauthority
```

> Now try

```
echo $DISPLAY
```

> again and you would see something like the following

```
localhost:10.0
```

> For fun try

```
xeyes
```

> Of course you could try xclock or any other as well

And it works in my case. Hope this is helpful and would solve a problem like the one above or like mine that someone has come across and who spent a few hours on this problem while scratching head and trying to pull hair out like me :-)).